# Load CSV file in S3 with AWS Glue in Scala

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, aws-glue

This should be easy...
For my AWS Glue job, I want to load my configuration settings from a CSV file on S3.  This way, my lambda function can trigger the job and send the file name as a parameter.  In Python, I can do this easily:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(<my bucket name>)
obj = s3.Object(<my bucket name>,<file location>)
data = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

In Scala, I can't find anything equivalent to the boto3 library.  I've tried the getSourceWithFormat function like this:

```
var datasource = glueContext.getSourceWithFormat("s3", JsonOptions(Map("paths" -> Set(<file folder name>)),
     Map("exclusions" -> <file patterns to exclude>)), 
     format = "csv", formatOptions = JsonOptions(Map("separator" -> "\t"),Map("header" -> true)))
     .getDynamicFrame()
```

but I'd like to just load a single file and manipulate it like an array of strings.

Thank you!

Comment: Something like this: https://index.scala-lang.org/bizreach/aws-s3-scala/aws-s3-scala/0.0.15?target=_2.12 ? You can look for Java/Scala S3 libraries - they'll give you access to files in your bucket. You can read your file depending on format: text, csv, binary, json, etc.

Comment: You can use [Benji S3](https://zengularity.github.io/benji/s3/usage.html) (I'm a contributor of), to read S3 object as Akka Stream `Source`, knowing that Akka provided a CSV framing.

Comment: You can have your lambda written in python and the Glue job in scala which can be called via lambda trigger if you didn't find equivalent scala code.

Comment: Thank you @bdcloud.  That's what I ended up doing.

Comment: @DouglasDaly please mark this as answered if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be going like this:

1. Write python code in Lambda to read the file.
2. Create your Glue job with scala code.
3. Make sure you have a trigger enabled which will call the Glue job with file names.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting your datasource to data frame, and then calling collect method on it ?

```
val  myArray = datasource.toDF().collect
```